# Repeating functions with python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I wish to know way to make loop of function to recreate the same shape/pattern([google photo logo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=google%20photo&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Ffscl01.fonpit.de%2Fuserfiles%2F3909760%2Fimage%2Fgoogle-photos.png)) with a different rotation and position and different variables such as color. Below is code that will allow me to make one of the pallets with the correct angles but ratio is not exact. Also prefer not use any goto/home function as I need repeat this drawing later. Should I have used left/right for direction instead of set heading?

```
def photo():
    speed(1) # turtle speed (debugging)
    #speed(0)
    length = 50

    penup()
    color("#4688f4") #Blue petal
    begin_fill() 
    setheading(25)
    forward(length/5.5)
    setheading(0)
    forward(length)
    setheading(227)
    forward(length*0.87)
    setheading(135)
    forward(length*0.8)
    end_fill()

    color("#3d6ec9") #Blue petal
    begin_fill() 
    setheading(250)
    forward(length/5)
    setheading(270)
    forward(length/2.6)
    setheading(0)
    forward(length/1.6)
    end_fill()
```

here you see the drawing from the code...

[image: thats the above described turtle drawing]

Update:

[image]

Comment: So.... youre just asking how a loop looks like?

Comment: you will need to put the above function into a loop, which will be done 4 times - after each loop, you will need to adjust your position. color-changes can be given to your function as parameters from a list. 

Before you go too deep into the coding, try thinking about where you land after each loop and where you have to go in order to start the next one!

Comment: How should I implemented this as the petal are rotated, do make these angle a variable and just add 90 degrees and for the starting position just move it desire location and basically paste what is above?

Comment: wrap the function call in a loop and add `turtle.tilt(angle)` at the end of your function definition to rotate the turtle after each drawing. replace angle with appropriate value

Comment: I was able to finish it via just copy above code and modify the starting location and adding 90 for second petal and 180 for the third and vice vera.

Comment: update looks great! and now try adapting it with loops, so you will need two lists for the different colors and let your function take 2 arguments - the both colors. then should be easy (y)

Comment: I presume a list for smaller/larger petal.

Comment: the list will only be used for the colors. the petals are basically two seperate drawings, which can be abstracted into functions as well! so you have one function with color 1 for the small petal and function 2 with color 1 dark for the big petal

Comment: @FlyingThunder, I don't believe your suggestion will work.  `tilt(angle)` tilts the turtle *image*, not it's direction, not the thing it's drawing.  A `right(90)` will likely work better.

Comment: Ah, right, was a long time ago that i used turtle, youre right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there like weird gap on blue petal while others don't?

To draw this cleanly, we need some sort of geometric model.  The one I'll use is a matching pair of right triangles with a base of 7 units and 45 degree angles:

[image]

I've put a red dot at what I consider the logical *origin* of our drawing.  To keep the math consistent, we'll cut the image we want out of the above figure:

[image]

> Should I have used left/right for direction instead of set heading?

The code to draw this figure and rotate it can't use `setheading()` as that's absolute and we have to draw relative to our logical origin:

```
from turtle import *

UNIT = 50

def photo(petal, shadow):

    right(45)  # move from "origin" to start of image
    forward(0.45 * UNIT)
    left(70)

    color(petal)

    begin_fill()
    forward(0.752 * UNIT)
    right(25)
    forward(6 * UNIT)
    right(135)
    forward(4.95 * UNIT)
    end_fill()

    right(45)

    color(shadow)

    begin_fill()
    forward(3.5 * UNIT)
    right(90)
    forward(2.5 * UNIT)
    right(25)
    forward(0.752 * UNIT)
    end_fill()

    left(70)  # return to "origin" where we started 
    forward(0.45 * UNIT)
    right(135)

penup()

for _ in range(4):
    photo("#4688f4", "#3d6ec9")
    left(90)

hideturtle()
mainloop()
```

[image]

I'll leave the coloring issue to you.

Answer (score 3):

very simplified answer:

```
my_colors =['blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'green'] # replace with hex values

for i in range(4):

    photo(my_colors[i])
    right(90)
```

`photo` function then needs to be adjusted to take a keyword, which could look like: `def photo(my_color):`, and where you use colors in your function, you just call it `color(my_color)`

but of course you need to think about where you will turn after each loop and if you will need to move forward as well.

Comment: You need to re-arange the list though, as in the picture you want to recreate blue+yellow / red+green are not adjacent. Critical Error!!1

Comment: :-D just picked 4 random colors  but thanks, critical error dodged!

Comment: I will look more into it but I figure a quick and dirty way of doing it but won't be as clean as using loops. I will do some more test!

Comment: Why is there like weird gap on blue petal while others don't? They basically have same code but alter angles. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOP8F.png

Comment: no idea! maybe because you calculate with weird numbers like `length*0.87` - this may be a cause for errors because of rounding